# Flask NameError: while flask_wtf and FlaskForm

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I usually have no problem adding forms to flask pages however this time I'm really struggling to find the specific issue.

Here are the details of my route:

```
@app.route("/add_recipe")
def add_recipe():
    form = abcForm()
    return render_template('add_recipe.html', title="Recipe", form= form)
```

Here is my form class

```
class abcForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login Up')
```

The error message I get is "NameError: name 'abcForm' is not defined"

Comment: You should show us the complete code, incl import statements. Also, when does the error occour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you are importing your form class into your route file.

```
from form-file-name import abcForm
```

Another thing to check, in your jinja template are you referring to your form as 'abcForm' instead of 'form'? It should be 'form' in jinja since you save it into form in your route.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was not importing the form class into the route file. This is now fixed thank you.